Visual Studio QtMsBuild build failed
Visual Studio 2022 with Qt5 shows this during build after no code change:

QtMsBuild\qt_vars.targets(512,5): error MSB4044: The "ReadLinesFromFile" task was not given a value for the required parameter "File".

Restart, rebuild, or change of code does not work.

Some code or MRE or code snippet is needed unless a value for file was not provided.

Caused by Qt VS Tools version 3.3.0
Right click on the failing project, select Qt -> Convert custom build steps to Qt/MSBuild.

Same problem on my VS 2019...
I solved it by downgrading my Qt-Extension for I noticed there was a newer version since Oct 22:

Deinstall your current Qt-Extension (Extensions -> Manage Extensions -> Installed ->  Uninstall "Qt Visual Studio Tools")
Go to https://download.qt.io/official_releases/vsaddin/ and download the previos version for your VS (for me it was  qt-vsaddin-msvc2019-x86-3.2.0-rev.47.vsix)
Before you install the older vsix, check that it won't get updated right after you will have installed it:

Either you will enable flightmode on your device and after the installation before you disable it, disable "Automatic updates" on the older now installed Extension
Otherwise you can disable generally automatically updates: Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Extensions: Now uncheck both "Automatically update extensions" checkboxes (If you still enable "Automatically check for updates" you will still get notified by VS).


Now install the downloaded older vsix by double-clicking it

For me, this is working very fine now. You may have to visit %QtMsBuild% and create a "qt.natvis.xml" file from "qt5.natvis.xml" if the build launches errors regarding this file.

I had the same problem. It comes with Qt VS Tools 3.3.0 added recently. The solution, as mention above is to:

disable automated update for Qt VS Tools extension
uninstall Qt VS Tools 3.3.0 version
install Qt VS Tools 3.2.0 version from https://download.qt.io/official_releases/vsaddin/
restart VS and recompile -> it will work

